# Inserting into a binary search tree

Tags: c++, exception, binary-search-tree, unhandled

I wrote a function to insert nodes into a binary search tree. However, when trying to build a solution in Visual Studio 2013, I receive this: "Unhandled exception at 0x00FD4CD0 in BST.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCCCCCCCC." The following is my code.

```
void BST::insert(int value) {
    Node* temp = new Node();
    temp->data = value;
    if(root == NULL) {
        root = temp;
        return;
    }
    Node* current;
    current = root;
    Node* parent;
    parent = root;
    current = (temp->data < current->data) ? (current->leftChild) : (current->rightChild);
    while(current != NULL) {
        parent = current;
        current = (temp->data < current->data) ? (current->leftChild) : (current->rightChild);
    }
    if(temp->data < parent->data) {
        parent->leftChild = temp;
    }
    if(temp->data > parent->data) {
        parent->rightChild = temp;
    }
}
```

Then in my main function I have:

```
int main() {
    BST bst;
    bst.insert(10);
    system("pause");
}
```

When I remove bst.insert(10); in my main function, I no longer receive the unhandled exception.

The following is the initialization of my struct

```
struct Node {
    int data;
    Node* leftChild;
    Node* rightChild;
    Node() : leftChild(NULL), rightChild(NULL) {} 
};
struct BST {
    Node* root;
    void insert(int value);
    BST() : root(NULL) {}
};
```

Comment: Post your `Node` class

Comment: edited in at the bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your insertion function you are not setting `leftChild` and `rightChild` to NULL.

```
void BST::insert(int value) {
    Node* temp = new Node();
    temp->data = value;
    temp->leftChild = NULL;
    temp->rightChild = NULL;
    if(root == NULL) {
        root = temp;
        return;
    }
```

Also, I cannot be sure (as you have not posted the constructor for `BST`) but you may not have set root to NULL in the `BST` constructor. Try with these modifications.

Seems like you do not have a constructor in BST from what you have posted:

```
struct BST {
    Node* root;
    void insert(int value);
    BST(): root(NULL) { } // add a constructor to initialize root to NULL
};
```

Comment: In my constructor BST (I edited that in the bottom) I set leftChild and rightChild to NULL, but not root. Would I do that in the BST constructor or the Node Constructor?

Comment: I edited it in my original post and it compiles, so was that the only reason for the 'unhandled exception'?

Comment: You were comparing root to NULL in `if(root == NULL)` to see if the BST is empty but you never set `root` to `NULL` in the first place. So `root` had a random garbage address and the `if(root == NULL)` check failed and execution went to the part of code below `if`. So, lot of memory access violations there.

Comment: Ok great, thanks. But what exactly does the error mean? When it tells me there is an unhandled exception, is it  giving the address of what root was ?

Comment: It tells you that the program is trying to access a memory address that is not allowed by the operating system. Read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault)